# loadHTML() completely blank page

Tags: php, php-7

For hours I ran circles around a function I'd written before realizing that `loadHTML()` simply isn't working.

In a new page I copied and pasted this example directly from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

It produces a blank page, no errors, nothing.

This is on a completely fresh Apache2 and PHP7 install on a VPS, very run-of-the-mill configuration, no funny business. I wondered if I'd installed PHP wrong somehow, but then all of my other PHP pages and functions are working fine. Am I just missing something really, really basic? I don't know how it can get any more basic than copying and pasting the example code directly from PHP.net!

Comment: What is the response from loadHTML()?

Comment: It worked for me. Must be something in your configuration.

Comment: place on line 2 `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);  ` and see if errors appear

Comment: @Difster yeah worked on my XAMPP. What in the config could cause specifically loadHTML to not work?

Comment: @IvoP Thanks, still nothing. Blank page, no errors.

Comment: Missing extensions. Did you check the logs or try `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: @Difster OK found some instructions on another question to run a search: `apt-cache search php-dom`, which revealed `php7.0-xml` was indeed missing. Installed, seems to work now, thanks! Curious why it wouldn't have installed though, PHP documentation says it should be enabled by default...

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? Sometimes they do their own php installs and leave stuff out for seemingly arbitrary reasons.

Comment: @Difster nope, on a VPS! Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I just looked through my command history and I did `sudo apt-get install php`, no options specified. I dunno what happened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably missing the php-dom or php-xml [extension](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php).

Comment: You were ultimately correct but I think this answer could have been more helpful with additional info! I found in a different question an instruction to search `apt-cache search php-dom`, which revealed that `php7.0-xml` was missing, and that was indeed the cause of this issue, despite it supposedly being enabled by default...

Comment: Couldn't really tell you what command you needed to install the extension, since it's different on every OS and you didn't list your OS. Glad I could be of help though!